# How to create custom dashed line

Tags: css

I want to create a component where it has a dashed line that looks like this, basically I want to add a **border-radius** to each dash, that make it curves like in the picture.

[image]

Here what I try so far:

```css
.line {
  height: 12px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right,#52cc7a 0,#52cc7a 6px,transparent 6px,transparent 18px)
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Comment: Repeating radial gradient if there is such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approximate it with a radial gradient:

```css
.line {
  height: 12px;
  background: 
   radial-gradient(4px 8px, #52cc7a 80%,transparent 87%) 0 0/20px 100%;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Comment: It's not that smooth

Comment: @ppwater that's why I said *approximate*

Comment: oh, sorry. didn't see that

Comment: i think this idea is pretty good enough for me, I can adjust the config to get the animation I want, thanks

Comment: You can extend the idea by drawing 3 background - two circles, top and bottom, and a rectangle in between and have background-repeat: repeat on each one. That would get you the shape you are aiming for.

Comment: @AHaworth sorry I can get your idea clearly. Can you help me draft it out?

Comment: Hi, I've put the idea up in an answer, though TBH for your use case of wanting a sort of divider then I think the answer here is pretty good, and simple! But it's fun seeing what can be done with overlapping background images so maybe my answer will help someone.

Comment: hi @TemaniAfif, there is one small problem, when I use your code and compile, there is warning ( not error) like this `Gradient has outdated direction syntax. New syntax is like 'closest-side at 0 0' instead of '0 0, closest-side'.` <= Do you know what is this and how to fix it ?

Comment: @JakeLam I am not using any of the syntax you are getting in the warning. It's for sure something else and not my code. The syntax I am using is not outdated

Comment: @TemaniAfif it seems that my programm tell warning in `4px 8px` part, when I check the full syntax of radial-gradient in here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_radial-gradient.asp . The first argument should have shape and size before position (which is `4px 8px` in your code I guess. )So I think it requires an exact size and shape but i tried all combination but no pairs works, do you have any recommend on this ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif thats great, thanks for the clarification, somehow my program need `ellipse 4px 8px at center` cause we have some strict css linting rules. Replace it with that just fixed my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We can draw several background images. Using circles for the top and bottom 'roundy' bits and a rectangle in the middle we can achieve something like in this snippet - the circles have been given different colors just to show what is going on, and the size has been magnified so we can check more easily on alignment.

I'm on a very old screen and the edges look a bit jagged but I'm hoping on a better display like retina it will seem smoother.

```css
.line {
  height:100px;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: radial-gradient(cyan 0, cyan 12px, transparent 12px, transparent 100%),radial-gradient(magenta 0, magenta 12px, transparent 12px, transparent 100%),linear-gradient(to right,#52cc7a 0,#52cc7a 24px,transparent 24px,transparent 100%);
  background-size: 60px 60px, 60px 60px, 60px 60px;
  background-position: -18px -15px, -18px 39px, 0 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat, no-repeat no-repeat, no-repeat no-repeat;
  }
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Of course, there needs to be fiddling around with sizes to get the exact spacing you want, and some thinking about what should happen on small screens versus large ones, how does it all fit in with the font size and so on.

Anyway, here's a snippet with the colors the same and repeated background images.

```css
.line {
          height:100px;
          width: 100vw;
          background-image: radial-gradient(#52cc7a 0, #52cc7a 12px, transparent 12px, transparent 100%),radial-gradient(#52cc7a 0, #52cc7a 12px, transparent 12px, transparent 100%),linear-gradient(to right,#52cc7a 0,#52cc7a 24px,transparent 24px,transparent 100%);
          background-size: 60px 60px, 60px 60px, 60px 60px;
          background-position: -18px -15px, -18px 39px, 0 12px;
          background-repeat: repeat no-repeat, repeat no-repeat, repeat no-repeat;
          }
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Comment: an optimized version of your code: https://jsfiddle.net/20wts5qc/

Comment: Thanks! much neater.

Comment: Ya, i think your answer also pretty great, thanks for sharing